# intermittent erros with android (google play) in-app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, intermittent

Some people trying to do in-app purchase within my Android game report that they can never complete the purchase -- that they always get an error message. (I.e., The market app reports an error to my application, and I show the user this error.)

Unfortunately, I don't have any real log data for this one, because it only happens for certain customers of my game, not for me.

What's strange is that after updating to a new version of the app, for some users the problem goes away, and for some users the problem starts. So user A might have the problem in version 1 of the app, but it clears up when they update to version 2. User B might not have the problem in version 1, but it appears when they update to version 2.

I say "intermittent" above, but by that I mean that it only seems to affect a small number of users. But for any given user, once they get in this state, they seem to get the message all the time. HOWEVER, I have had *some* cases where the problem does clear up suddenly, without an app update. I'm not sure if, for instance, power cycling, or, say, making an in-app-purchase in another app is away to "break out" of this state.

I realize that without a specific error message or API call to name/blame, this question is difficult to answer. I'm just trying to understand if this pattern -- of some users mysteriously getting stuck in a state where they are unable to make any in-app-purchase within a given app -- sounds familiar to anyone for Google Play in-app-purchase.

Also, I build my apps on top of Marmalade, so it's possible that the problem is in the Marmalade layer, not in my app or in the Google Play market itself.

Answer (score -1):

The same problem here: a lot of users can buy items in my app but some users send me emails complaining why they can't buy considering that they can successful purchase items in other apps. I think it occurs because of a temporary problem on the Google Play server or is something to do with the service on Android. I am still looking for an answer to this weird problem...